# co_await inside catch no longer compiling with GCC12

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-coroutine, gcc12

I have a code that looks like this:

```
auto func() -> asio::awaitable<void> {
    try {
        co_await async_operation();
    } catch(boost::system::system_error const& e) {
        co_return co_await another_async_operation();
    }
}
```

This code worked perfectly with GCC 11, but with GCC 12 it won't compile:

```
file.cpp:3:19: error: await expressions are not permitted in handlers
  3 |         co_return co_await another_async_operation();
    |                   ^~~~~~~~
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explicitly forbidden in [[expr.await]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.await#2):

> An await-expression shall appear only in a potentially-evaluated expression within the compound-statement of a function-body outside of a handler ([except.pre]).

The error message here is pretty clear: you can't await in an exception handler. That it compiled before is a bug, this was always the rule ([P0912R5](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0912r5.html)).